# Spring: @Autowired not working with ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I just wanted to print all the beans that have been loaded, and I understand the `getBeanDefinitionNames()` method is what a lot of people suggest. For this I understand you need an `ApplicationContext` which I autowired as below, but I am getting a null pointer exception on the object when I call `getBeanDefinitionNames()` on it:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

public class BeansPrinter 
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public void printBeans()
    {
        System.out.println("Number of beans:");
        System.out.println(appContext.getBeanDefinitionCount());

        String[] names = appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for(String name : names)
        {
            System.out.println("-----------------");
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        BeansPrinter b = new BeansPrinter();
        b.printBeans();
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Component` is missing from your `BeansPrinter` class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BeansPrinter is not a spring bean. The Autowiring will only work if the parent is a spring bean.

Annotate your BeansPrinter with `@Component` or `@Service`

```
@Service("beansPrinter")
public class BeansPrinter
```

and in your main class you could do something like:

```
 ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

and then `ctx.getBean("beansPrinter")` to get your bean

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick